# Allow different maxOccurs inside unbounded choice via XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-parsing, xml-validation

```
XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Credits>
         <Director>Movie</Director>
         <Director>Movie</Director>
         <Director>Movie</Director>
         <Producer />
         <Producer />
         <Actor>Jules Verne</Actor>
         <Producer />
         <Actor>Jules Verne</Actor>
         <Actor>Jules Verne</Actor>
</Credits>

XSD:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Credits">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Director" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Producer" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Actor" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="Writer" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

How can I define XSD to restrict Actor to maxOccurs 1 and Writer to maxOccurs as 5 and rest as unbounded? Order of elements can vary.

Answer (score 0):

In XSD 1.0, it's for practical purposes impossible (it can be done in principle by defining all possible combinations, but that's absurdly complex).

In XSD 1.1 you can use `xsd:any` with maxOccurs values on each of the particles.

Question: why do you want to do this? Why would you want to disallow movies with more than 5 writers? Is it some fundamental law of physics that movies can't have six writers?

Comment: thanks .requirement is :
-All my elements are at root level(no nesting)
-certain elements need to be allowed only once &some other fixed times
-I need to validate i.e. if an element is allowed only 5 times I want to check that
-The elements should need not be ordered

based on above requirements(and my limited XSD knowledge) I tried below options:
1.Using Sequence:Doesnt work as elements can come in any order
2.Using all:Doesnt work as some elements can appear more than once.
3.Using Choice with unbounded as maxOccurs: Works partially but not able to define maxOccurs for each element.

Comment: I understand what rules you want to apply, I'm just very curious as to why. A system that allows you to publish a paper with five authors, but not with six, strikes me as a pretty bad system.

Comment: thats the thing.. so it is a custom designed XSD in which certain validations need to be added. I know not the ideal way but as of now cannot change the design due to project constraints.. :)

Comment: I was just asking out of curiosity what those constraints were. If I were on this project I would be arguing with people and telling them they've got the requirements wrong.